# Manhattan/Tchebyshev Distance - O(n^3) Solution

Tags: java, algorithm

This is a variant of the Manhattan Distance problem. The input is a 2D matrix of boolean with the `true` cells representing location of an ATMs(or anything for that matter). The output has to be a 2D int matrix giving the distance of each cell from the location of the closest ATMS.

Here's my code,

```
public class ManhattanDistance {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean[][] check = new boolean[5][5];
        check[0] = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false};
        check[1] = new boolean[]{false, false, true, false, false};
        check[2] = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false};
        check[3] = new boolean[]{true, false, true, false, false};
        check[4] = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, true};

        printArray(check);
        int[][] grid = manhattanDistance(check);
        System.out.println("____________________________________");
        printArray(grid);
    }

    public static int[][] manhattanDistance(boolean[][] checkList){
        int[][] grid = new int[checkList.length][checkList[0].length];
        for (int i = 0; i <grid.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length ; j++) {
                 grid[i][j] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <checkList.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < checkList[i].length; j++) {
                 if(checkList[i][j]) spiral(i, j, grid);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <grid.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <grid[i].length ; j++) {
                 if(checkList[i][j]) grid[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        return grid;
    }

    public static void spiral(int row, int col, int[][] grid){

        boolean[] conditionChecker = new boolean[8];
        int rowMax = grid.length;
        int colMax = grid[0].length;

           while(true){
               int level = 0;
               //up
               if(!conditionChecker[0]) {
                   while(row -1 >= 0){
                       grid[row-1][col] = Math.min(grid[row-1][col], level+1);

                       level++;
                       row--;
                   }
                   row += level;
                   level = 0;
                   conditionChecker[0] = true;
               }

               //down
               if (!conditionChecker[1]){
                   while(row + 1 < rowMax){
                       grid[row +1][col] = Math.min(grid[row+1][col], level+1);

                       level++;
                       row++;
                   }
                   row -= level;
                   level =0;
                   conditionChecker[1] = true;
               }

               //right
               if(!conditionChecker[2]){
                   while(col + 1 < colMax){
                       grid[row][col +1] = Math.min(grid[row][col+1], level+1);
                       level++;
                       col++;
                   }
                   col -= level;
                   level = 0;
                   conditionChecker[2] = true;
               }

               //left
               if (!conditionChecker[3]){
                   while(col -1 >= 0){
                       grid[row][col -1] = Math.min(grid[row][col-1], level+1);
                       level++;
                       col--;
                   }
                   col+= level;
                   level = 0;
                   conditionChecker[3] = true;
               }

               //NE
               if(!conditionChecker[4]) {
                   while(row -1 >= 0 && col +1 < colMax){
                       grid[row-1][col+1] = Math.min(grid[row-1][col+1], level+1);
                       row--;
                       col++;
                       level++;
                   }
                   row+= level;
                   col-= level;
                   level = 0;
                   conditionChecker[4] = true;
               }

               //SE
               if(!conditionChecker[5]){
                   while(row +1 < rowMax && col +1 < colMax){
                       grid[row+1][col+1] = Math.min(grid[row+1][col+1], level+1);
                       row++;
                       col++;
                       level++;
                   }
                   row -= level;
                   col -= level;
                   level = 0;
                   conditionChecker[5] = true;
               }

               //NW
               if(!conditionChecker[6]){
                   while(row +1 < rowMax && col -1 >= 0){
                       grid[row+1][col-1] = Math.min(grid[row+1][col-1], level + 1);
                       level++;
                       row++;
                       col--;
                   }
                   row-= level;
                   col += level;
                   level = 0;
                   conditionChecker[6] = true;
               }

               //SW
               if(!conditionChecker[7]){
                   if(row -1 >= 0 && col -1 >= 0){
                       grid[row-1][col-1] = Math.min(grid[row-1][col-1], level+1);
                       row--;
                       col--;
                       level++;
                   }
                   row += level;
                   col += level;
                   level = 0;
                   conditionChecker[7] = true;
               }

               if(conditionChecker[7]) break;
           }
    }


    public static void printArray(int[][] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <arr[0].length ; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] +" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void printArray(boolean[][] arr){
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <arr[0].length ; j++) {
                if(!arr[i][j])System.out.print(0 +" ");
                else System.out.print(1+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The core algorithm is as follows.

> 1. Initialize an integer matrix with a very large number for all cells.
> 2. Traverse the boolean matrix
> 3. For every cell with an ATM spin up a search in all 8 cardinal directions level by level.
> 4. For every level of search the existing number is over written by a smaller number should a smaller level exist.

Invite comments and suggestions for betterment.

Comment: Under the usual definition of Manhattan distance, there are only four directions, because you cannot travel diagonally.  The distance from (0, 0) to (1, 1) is 2.

Comment: Yup that's why I've mentioned  'a variant.'

Comment: Is this [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance)?

Comment: Infact I wasn't aware of this, but looks like this is `Tchebyshev Distance`

Comment: (`O(n³)`: n is O(#columns+#rows)?) I'd start at the algorithmic level: Keep a queue of boundary pieces to process. `Initialise integer matrix cells with large number`. Start with zero "at the ATMs", inserting each in queue. Take boundary piece from the queue, increase values "just outside", splitting boundary pieces at matrix boundaries (there's a problem here with same distance from multiple matrix boundaries), joining if encountering same value (lower shouldn't happen). _If_ that works, it should be O(n²). (If the question is how to best code the approach presented, pls make that explicit.)